# PHP + ORACLE connection problem

Tags: php, oracle

My error code is :

```
Warning: ocilogon() [function.ocilogon]: OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that ORACLE_HOME is set and points to the right directory in /data01/app/htdocs/doosanclub/include/classes.pinc on line 47
```

and the line 47 is :

```
46:     function connect($DBuser,$DBpassword,$DBsid) {
47:        $this->conn = OCILogon($DBuser,$DBpassword,$DBsid);
48:        $this->mode = OCI_DEFAULT;
49:    }
```

My ORACLE_HOME is set in root.sh : `ORACLE_HOME=/oracle`

and `/oracle` is a correct directory that contains `/bin`.

and.. my $DBsid value is also defined in `/oracle/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`.

I googled some [docs](http://www.eckford.ca/OpenSourceDev/subjects/UbuntuServer/php-oci8.php) and try it. I made a test php file.
THe code is :

```
oci_internal_debug(1);   // turn on tracing
$conn = oci_connect("id", "pw", "SID");
```

and it displays :

```
OCI8 DEBUG: OCINlsEnvironmentVariableGet at (/temp/php_source/php-5.2.13/ext/oci8/oci8.c:1067) OCI8 DEBUG: OCIEnvNlsCreate at (/temp/php_source/php-5.2.13/ext/oci8/oci8.c:1223) 
Warning: oci_connect() [function.oci-connect]: OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that ORACLE_HOME is set and points to the right directory in /data01/app/htdocs/doosanclub/db_connect_test.php on line 23
OCI8 DEBUG: OCIHandleFree at (/temp/php_source/php-5.2.13/ext/oci8/oci8.c:1547)
```

`ORACLE_HOME` again.. maybe it is wrong..? I don't know..

It's the first time to setup these things.
Please help me out this problem. Thanks!

Comment: may be it's some file-permissioin issue? under what user apache runs php scripts? does it have permissions to read /oracle directory?

Comment: What do you see in the ENVIRONMENT when you run "phpinfo()"

Comment: James Anderson // what kind of info do you need to know to solve this problem? I'm very sorry, but I can't give you the whole info because of security problem.

Comment: heximal // This site is running in Unix server as a "root".

Comment: @Deckard: what James is getting at is that maybe the PHP is running in a different environment. What happens if you prefix the oci_connect() call with 'print $_ENV['ORACLE_HOME'];' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem just by adding putenv() into a DB connecting PHP file.

```
putenv("ORACLE_HOME=/oracle");
```

But it's very weird that `phpinfo();` displays `ORACLE_HOME=/oracle` before I set `ORACLE_HOME`.